# Jquery mobile Tabs not working on external page

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have index.html that contains few divs with "page" role.
In one of these pages I have a link to a different html page. 
When I click on the link, the 2nd html page opens and looks nicely themed and the buttons are working fine.
The issue is that the tabs are not working. When i click on the nav buttons they don't change to the correct tab. What am I doing wrong?

The link on index.html:

```
<a class="ui-link ui-btn ui-btn-b ui-shadow ui-corner-all" role="button" href="MemberPay.htm?Name=John&MemberID=23" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Pay</a>
```

The 2nd html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
<div id="MemberPay_Page" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" data-theme="b" >


    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Get Payment</h1>
    </div>

    <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content jqm-fullwidth"  >                              

        <form dir="rtl">


            <label id="lblMemberID">member id:</label>                 


            <div data-role="tabs" id="tbPaymentMethod">
                  <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#tabCash">מזומן</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#tabCcard">כ.אשראי</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#tabCheck">צ'ק</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tabCash">
                    <p>This is the content of the tab 'One', with the id fragment-1.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tabCcard">
                    <p>This is the content of the tab 'Two', with the id fragment-2.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div id="tabCheck">
                    <p>This is the content of the tab 'Three', with the id fragment-3.</p>
                  </div>
            </div>


            <a  href="" data-transition="flip" data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" onclick="SavePayment()">Save</a>                                                  

        </form>

    </div><!-- /content -->

</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in your firebug/console?

Comment: it's a bug in jQM 1.4 https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7169

Comment: alternatively, you can create tabs dynamically before page is shown.

Comment: @Omar, what do you mean by "create tabs dynamically"?

Comment: this is what I mean http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/s4ZM6/

Comment: Very nice. Thank you very much for your help. Can you add this with your comment about the bug to an answer so I can mark it as right answer?