# jQuery Mobile displays all Tab containers on linked page

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery Mobile. I'm trying to implement a site using a main index.html (containing header, footer and main Page body) and multiple Page partials (one page per file).

One of the partials that gets swapped into that body uses the Tabs widget. When I trigger the link to this page, the tabs load "flat", as one would expect when the jQUI/jQM code doesn't work its magic.

If I put this same markup in index.html, it looks fine. My guess is that something needs to run to initialize the secondary page, but I don't know what. I'm already listening for `pagechange`, but don't know what to call to initialize the Tabs widget.

I threw the code into this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YMxWUSKA2zsVTOSoqn6D?p=preview), but jQM doesn't seem to work there (only jQUI?).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [Jquery mobile Tabs not working on external page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22541365/356016), which references [jQM issue 7169](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7169). The fix is targeted for version 1.5.

A workaround is given in [this comment](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7169#issuecomment-36005377), from gabrielschulhof:

```
$.widget( "ui.tabs", $.ui.tabs, {
    _createWidget: function( options, element ) {
        var page, delayedCreate,
            that = this;

        if ( $.mobile.page ) {
            page = $( element )
                .parents( ":jqmData(role='page'),:mobile-page" )
                .first();

            if ( page.length > 0 && !page.hasClass( "ui-page-active" ) ) {
                delayedCreate = this._super;
                page.one( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
                    delayedCreate.call( that, options, element );
                });
            }
        } else {
            return this._super();
        }
    }
});
```